# How to convert HTML to JSX (React.js)

Tags: html, reactjs, jsx, converters

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/@daily-co/daily-js"></script>
<script>
  callFrame = window.DailyIframe.createFrame();
  callFrame.join({ url: 'https://your-team.daily.co/hello' })
</script>
</body>
```

This code is trying to display a video function by embedding. I need to convert this to jsx to add it to my webpage or find another way to create a video call using react.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use https://magic.reactjs.net/htmltojsx.htm which is an online HTML to JSX compiler.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer works well but it doesn't have syntax highlighting.

You can use https://divmagic.com/tools/html-to-jsx if you want that.

Answer (score 0):

you can use html-to-jsx-transform package to convert your html code to jsx, or there are many packages or cdn also.

```js
import { htmlToJsx } from "html-to-jsx-transform";

const jsx = htmlToJsx('<h1 tabindex="0">Hello World!</h1>');

// jsx === '<h1 tabIndex={0}>Hello World!</h1>';
```

Answer (score -1):

As described in the [daily-js docs](https://docs.daily.co/reference#using-the-dailyco-front-end-library)

Install the daily-co node package.

```
npm install @daily-co/daily-js
```

Then create a component that uses it.

```
// webpack/node-style require
//
const DailyIframe = require('@daily-co/daily-js');
let callFrame = DailyIframe.wrap(MY_IFRAME);

// or, cutting-edge, super-whizzy import
//
import DailyIframe from '@daily-co/daily-js';
let callFrame = DailyIframe.wrap(MY_IFRAME);
```

Answer (score -1):

There is some tools online that convert Html to jsx and react components for exemple
https://helpfordev.com/html-to-jsx

Answer (score -1):

You can also use https://transform.tools/html-to-jsx beside  https://magic.reactjs.net/htmltojsx.htm as mentioned above.

Answer (score -1):

When converting HTML to JSX there are five steps you need to apply:

1. All prop names follow camelCase
2. Number attributes use curly braces
3. Boolean 'true' can be written with just the property name. 'False' should be written with curly braces
4. The 'class' attribute is written as 'className'
5. In-line styles are provided as objects